# referecia id do usuario logado se perdendo

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core

Estou fazendo um projeto de cartão ponto Net Core MVC, em que tenho cadastro de usuario, empresa e funcionario. Pra cadastrar a empresa preciso pegar o id do usuario logado, ja tenho um função que faz isso e funciona pq uso pra cadastrar endereços.

```
// GET: Empresas/Create
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Nova empresa");
        var usuario = await _usuarioRepositorio.PegarUsuarioLogado(User);
        var empresa = new Empresa {UsuarioId = usuario.Id}; //aqui tem a referencia do ID certinho
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Empresas/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("EmpresaId,CNPJ,RazaoSocial,NomeFantasia,RamoAtividade,InscEstadual,InscMunicipal,Telefone,Email,Rua,Numero,Bairro,Cidade,Estado,UsuarioId")] Empresa empresa)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await _empresaRepositorio.Inserir(empresa);//mas quando passa pra cá ela se perde e fica como "NULL"

            _logger.LogInformation("Novo empresa cadastrado");
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Usuarios");
            //return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        _logger.LogError("Informações inválidas");
        return View(empresa);
    }
```

na declaração de empresa tem o UsuarioID, mas quando passa pela view e vai inserir perde a referencia (consigui confirmar isso atraves do debugger), qual sera o motivo de ter perdido?

na views->Empresa->Create tenho a vizualização de todos os campos, e o usuarioID esta oculto

```
<input asp-for="UsuarioId" type="hidden" />
```

Comment: No método `Create()` vc não está passando o objeto empresa, tente `return View(empresa)`

Comment: @VanderleiPires era isso mesmo, obrigada!

Answer (score 1):

Você não está retornando a empresa para a View.

Tente fazer assim:

```
// GET: Empresas/Create
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Nova empresa");
        var usuario = await _usuarioRepositorio.PegarUsuarioLogado(User);
        var empresa = new Empresa {UsuarioId = usuario.Id};
        return View(**empresa**);
    }
```

Após isto, certifique-se de que sua view esteja retornando o objeto empresa para a controller no POST.